# Strongly unbiased symmetric monoidal category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. Define a *strongly unbiased symmetric monoidal structure* on $\mathcal{C}$ to be a rule which associates to every finite set $I$ a functor $\mathcal{C}^I \to \mathcal{C}$, written $(A_i)_{i \in I}  \mapsto \bigotimes_{i \in I} A_i$ on objects (and likewise on morphisms), equipped with natural isomorphisms
$$\bigotimes_{i \in \{j\}} A_i \cong A_j$$
$$\forall \sigma : I \xrightarrow{\cong} J :~~ \bigotimes_{\large i \in I} A_{\sigma(i)} \cong \bigotimes_{\large j \in J} A_j $$
$$\forall (J_i)_{i \in I} : ~~\bigotimes_{\large i \in I} \bigotimes_{\large j \in J_i} A_j \cong \bigotimes_{\large j \in \coprod_{i \in I} J_i} A_j$$
subject to some coherence conditions (which should be easy to work out).

**Question 1.** Where does this definition appear in the literature? Perhaps with another name?

**Question 2.** There is an obvious notion of morphism between strongly unbiased symmetric monoidal structures; and likewise for the usual biased version. What is a reference for the result that there is an equivalence of categories between (unbiased symmetric monoidal structures on $\mathcal{C}$) and (symmetric monoidal structures on $\mathcal{C}$)?

I do not ask how to prove this (probably it is merely a restatement of the Coherence Theorem for symmetric monoidal categories); instead, I would like to ask for a detailed reference which is at best citable.

**Question 3.** There is a $2$-category of strongly unbiased symmetric monoidal categories. For example, a lax morphism between strongly unbiased symmetric monoidal categories $(\mathcal{C},\otimes) \to (\mathcal{D},\otimes)$ is a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$  equipped with natural morphisms $\bigotimes_{i \in I} F(A_i) \to F(\bigotimes_{i \in I} A_i)$, subject to some coherence conditions. Is there a reference for the result that this $2$-category is equivalent to the $2$-category of (biased) symmetric monoidal categories?

Notice that this was already asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207966), but the answers are not satisfactory. Therefore let me also remark that, in this case, I am *not* interested in "related" or "similar" questions. Notice that Questions 1 and 2 are *partially* answered by Proposition 1.5 in Deligne-Milne's *Tannakian categories*, but they only indicate the results without proper reasoning and without giving the strongly unbiased structures a proper name.

Comment: In the definition of a strongly unbiased symmetric monoidal category, there are 7 coherence diagrams.

Comment: We'll see if any answers turn up, but I wouldn't be surprised at all if this were unwritten folklore.

Comment: I'm not sure that for Question 2 you really need to use the coherence theorem; it feels more like proving that the category of finite sets is equivalent to it's skeleton. Pick for each finite set $I$ a bijection $\beta_I : I \to \{1, 2, \cdots, |I|\}$ so that $\beta_{\{1,2,\cdots,n\}}$ is the identity and use those $\beta_I$'s to construct a strongly unbiased symmetric monoidal category given an unbiased one. I haven't thought it through but I wouldn't expect you need coherence to prove this is an equivalence (I could easily be wrong).

Comment: Did this ever get worked out?  I need it for a lecture I'm giving tomorrow.

Comment: @JohnBaez: A year ago I started to write up what I had proven so far (hence, this is far from being complete or proofread!): https://www.dropbox.com/s/seffmb47ipj9so5/sym-mon-cat-unbiased.pdf?dl=0